# UIScrollView stops scrolling after adding UILabel on Storyboard

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uilabel

I encountered a strange problem while working with the UIScrollView and UILabel.

My viewDidLoad function looks like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad

    [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    scrollViewContent.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 960);
    scrollViewContent.scrollEnabled = YES;
}
```

If I add UILabel on Storyboard scroller stops scrolling.
Also i added label as subview but this does not change anything

```
[scrollViewContent addSubview:labelHeader];
```

Does anyone had a similar problem or know a solution?

Comment: I have had this problem as well but don't have a solution. in XCode 4.6.x I was fine doing this with xib files.

Comment: Do you have autolayout enabled or disabled in your project?

Comment: autolayout is enabled

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this problem once and solved it with this simple fix:

In storyboard mode first select your UIScrollView and then open the "Resolve Auto Layout Issues"-menu. Click the option: "Add missing constraints".